# Does an uncharged capacitor in a non uniform electric field have a voltage difference at its terminals?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance

If an uncharged capacitor was placed in a dc field would there be a voltage difference developed on its terminals related to the different locations of the two surfaces in the voltage field? Would the result vary depending on the dielectric between the plates?

Answer (score 0):

It does not gain charge, but it does show a voltage. Consider a 1D space with an electric field. If you place voltmeter probes into that space, the voltmeter will show a voltage proportional to the separation of the probes. In fact, that's how field strength is measured. The voltage appears because the probe leads conduct their voltages to the same location (that of the voltmeter). If you then place the plates of an uncharged capacitor into that space such that one plate touches each probe, the voltmeter will still show the same voltage. So we see that in this case, we need to better define what we mean by "capacitor voltage" and "capacitor charge". If we define it as "what a voltmeter registers when connected to the capacitor leads", then the answer is yes, the capacitor gains a voltage (but not charge), and it is proportional to the plate separation and the electric field (in a 1D space). Of course, that extra voltage does not represent any extra energy stored in the capacitor.

Comment: I don't think this is right, real voltmeters rely on current to infer the voltage at a point. If there's no current, the voltmeters will always measure zero.

Comment: I presume that there will be separation of charges on each plate such that there will be equal and opposite charges on the 'inside' and 'outside' surface of each plate. In that way, $Q=CV$ will still apply, but $Q$ will be the magnitude of the charge on each inside surface.

Comment: @PhilipWood Yes but can you then say that the capacitor has now stored energy of $\frac{CV^2}{2}$? I would think not since no charge has been added to the plates. Right?

Comment: @EnriqueMendez Agree voltmeters require current but I think the current doesn't necessarily have to come from the circuit being measured. It's my understanding that in the old vacuum tube voltmeters (VTVMs) and the modern replacement using field effect transistors (FETs) current is supplied by the instrument. But I could be wrong.